# Next-Auth warning-issue

Tags: next.js, facebook-authentication, next-auth

I'm working on a Facebook clone code along.
I am pretty new to Next.js

it throws an error at me which I'm not sure if it is standard or some bug in my code.

```
https://next-auth.js.org/warnings#no_secret
[next-auth][warn][NO_SECRET]
```

Can anyone explain it please ?

```
[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ]
})
```

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import {SessionProvider} from "next-auth/react"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  
  )}

export default MyApp
```

````
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=495472355295570
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=secret is from facebook for developers
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000```
````

Comment: You need to provide a secret in production, see https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret.

Answer (score 5):

NEXTAUTH_URL is the canonical URL of your site.

## for development, NEXTAUTH_URL looks like

`NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/`

## for production, NEXTAUTH_URL looks like

`NEXTAUTH_URL=http://officialrajdeepsingh.dev`

Read more about NEXTAUTH_URL details of docs
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options

Comment: what is this http://officialrajdeepsingh.dev?

Comment: NEXTAUTH_URL=http://your-domain.com

or

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://officialrajdeepsingh.dev

both same the basic meaning of that pass domain name. for example I pass http://officialrajdeepsingh.dev

Answer (score 3):

For your production phase, e.g. let's say your're deploying on Vercel.
You need your app's secret key. 
Further readings. [what is missings secret](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#missing-secret) and [what is secret](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#secret)

#### To fix:

1. You need your application's secret which can be generated via [this like by varcel](https://generate-secret.vercel.app/32)
2. **You set NEXTAUTH_SECRET** in your .env.local like

   NEXTAUTH_SECRET=af017d04a8083251abdebb81b1fbb498
3. **You add your secret to the file [...nextauth].js** like this(process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET) because you don't want to expose the key.

   `...`

   `export default NextAuth({`

      `...`

      `providers: [...],`

      `secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,`

      `...`

   `})`
4. You **add your secret on your vercel project** [like this](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-add-vercel-environment-variables).

That's all, the problem should be gone. Unless you deploy on other platform, the configuration might be different.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export default NextAuth({
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET
        })
    ],
secret: process.env.YOUR_SECRET
})
```

Just add the secret and it should be ok